# Запросы/ответы xml в Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, request

Мне нужно сделать форму, которая при нажатии кнопки отправляла бы xml-запрос на внешний сервер и получает от него ответ. Сделала, но в ответ приходит ошибка.
Код следующего вида:

```
class CreateX(CreateView):
form_class=XForm
template_name = 'form.html'

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    send_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xrrp><command>hello!</command></xrrp>'
    url = "http://197.0.0.1:7070"
    res=requests.post(url, data=send_xml, headers={'Conetent-Type': 'application/xml'})
    if res.status_code == 200:
        return HttpResponse(res.content, content_type='application/xml')
    else:
        return HttpResponse(res.status_code, content_type='application/xml')
```

Проверяла сервер через telnet - работает, показывает xml состояния. Проверяла общение на локальном сервере - ответы приходят. Следовательно, я обращаюсь к действующему серверу как-то неправильно. В панике перебирала разные советы из инета. 
При обращении по адресу url = "http://197.0.0.1:7070" ошибка имеет следующий вид:

```
ConnectionError at /form/
('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x00\x00\x00´<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'))
```

А при url = "https://197.0.0.1:7070"

```
SSLError at /form/
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='197.0.0.1', port=7070): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_record', 'wrong version number')])")))
```

Чувствую, что недопонимаю какие-то основополагающие вещи, поэтому не могу найти причину ошибок.

Comment: Вы уверены, что этот ваш внешний сервер является http-сервером?

Comment: не уверена и склоняюсь ко мнению, что не http - ставит меня в тупик

Comment: Если нет, тогда совершенно неудивительно, что на http-запрос от вас сервер не может нормально ответить. Спрашивайте администратора сервера, как правильно общаться с сервером

Comment: а можно как-то самой определить как к нему обратиться? либо это может быть нестандартизировано? мне скинули рhp запросы, но не знаю как переварить их для джанго.

Comment: Мы понятия не имеем, что там у вас за сервер, так что может быть абсолютно что угодно. Из того, что я вижу в BadStatusLine, я могу предположить, что сервер в ответе прислал четыре байта длины ответа в виде целого числа little endian (вероятно, это 180 байт) и следом за ним само тело xml-ответа — и это всё нужно разбирать вручную, а не через requests, который умеет только http-протокол. Но это не точно, и больше мне сказать нечего — спрашивайте администратора сервера или кого-то ещё приближенного к нему.

Comment: andreymal, спасибо!